# what I am supposed to do on edits like this?

Tags: discussion

[image]

In the above Image edit was suggested by unknown user. That edit seems to be not spam and related to user Question. But I dont know whether OP has tried this or not because It was posted with unknown user name.

what I am  thinking is , how about one more option that asking the editer as " are you the original user who posted the Question " ?

Pros:

- so that we can believe that the user tried this also with out any doubt on the editor and The answers can be more effective.

Cons:

- what if spam posted and clicked as original user ?

solution:

- what ever the edit it is should come across the Review/ Suggested Edits. So we usually catch it and going to remove it.

Just a Suggestion ,decision is yours.

Comment: Well, I normally reject those, as all in fair, I have no way to know if it's the same user, or another user with a "me too" case. One of the reasons I wanted [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7265/require-obligatory-user-registration) implemented.

Comment: I normally approve them, as do most reviewers AFIAK.

Comment: I reject these too, this kind of thing should be added as a comment instead.

Comment: @TomBrossman If the person trying to edit is the OP they *should not* add this information as a comment, rather edit it in (like they're trying to do) so that people don't have to hunt through the comments to find important information.

Comment: @Seth If the person editing is the OP they can already edit without needing approval. I agree comments are less useful but 2 accounts = 2 people, unless they explain themselves. I don't assume the person editing is the OP.

Comment: @TomBrossman Usually when this happens it *is* the OP, except he can't edit anymore because he didn't register and his cookies got cleared. Anyway, in this case if the editor was *not* the OP they should just ask a new question anyways.

Comment: I reject any edit that changes the "meaning" or "result" of a posting. This added a result (changes the result), but wasn't by the original author.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case, my recommendation would be to reject this.

> Invalid Edit - This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or
>   comment on the existing post.

Anonymous users are just that - you really can't second guess if this is actually the OP or another user.

Lets assume this is another user - their case could be quite different i.e. the OP's question, `nomodeset` could actually help.